# Avoid double components with single element components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm often creating components styled with `styled-component` that only consist of a single element, e.g:

```
const StyledButton = styled.button({
  color: '#fff',
  borderRadius: '2px'
})

const Button = ({ children, ...rest }) => (
  <StyledButton {...rest}>{children}</StyledButton>
)

export default Button
```

It feels redundant to have nested components. **Is there a more terse way to accomplish the above?**

1. I've tried to do a `export default`, but then the React dev tools doesn't recognize the component and displays it as "Unknown".
2. To my understanding, it isn't possible to pass `children` to a `styled-component`?

Comment: It is actually possible, you can use it like `<StyledButton>Whatever you want</StyledButton>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just wanted to render children and pass on props, there is no need to create the extra `Button` component. Instead you can just export `StyledButton` and use it as in:

```
<StyledButton onClick={buttonProp}>Children you want</StyledButton>
```

With this approach, you might miss out on the names for components, they show up as `styled.button` in devtools. To overcome this, there are two methods depending on the version.

1. Use the [babel plugin](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/tooling#babel-plugin) for styled components. 
   You can install it with

   npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-styled-components

   and use it by adding it to babel plugins:

   {
     "plugins": ["babel-plugin-styled-components"]
   }
2. If you 4.0 or above, you can make use of the [babel macro](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/tooling#babel-macro)
   Just change your imports to:

   ```
   import styled from 'styled-components/macro';

   const StyledButton = styled.button`
     color: red;
   `
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to nest the element, you can export it directly.

`<SomeComp {...rest}>{children}</SomeComp>`

is equivalent to

`<SomeComp {...props} />`

so you do not need to separate the children and nest them.